# What is the best Pantone swatch to use for on-screen designs?

Tags: website-design, pantone, swatches, e-mail

If my work is going to only be used to create image files that will be used online, or in email messages, what is the best Pantone swatch for me to use?

Comment: A swatch is a single color, perhaps you mean color book or library?

Comment: Why do you want to use Pantone? RGB is all you need.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm new at this and did not know that.

Comment: Hi bobkap, welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Stack Exchange only allows one account per user on a site.  Please go to our [help section](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Pantone is only actually used to reliably recreate colours *in offset printing*. If the end use of your product is RGB, then RGB colours are all you need—just like AAGD suggested in the comments. Pantone swatches are not something you should use or worry about in on-screen-only designs.

Of course, you could still use a Pantone colour book to find a colour you like and then use a conversion table to use a similar hue in your design. As to *what* Pantone hue you'd use, that is entirely up to you and depends on your design, style and tastes.